# Social media links on my site & SEO

Tags: seo, html, nofollow

How should I give URL to my social accounts on my web page, to make perfect SEO?

with `nofollow` attribute as like this?

```
<a href='http://www.facebook.com/example' rel='nofollow'>
We Are In Facebook!</a>
```

without `nofollow` attribute as like this?

```
<a href='http://www.facebook.com/example'>
We Are In Facebook!</a>
```

or with a redirect as like this?

```
<a href='http://www.example.com/redirect.php?url=http://www.face
book.com/example'>We Are In Facebook!</a>
```

Comment: Related: [Should I use rel=“nofollow” for social media links?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/52877/17633)

Comment: ok... but, do you have any idea why we dont see rel='me' on any (ANY) big sites? such as newspapers washingtonpost.com, nytimes.com etc; you may check all..

Comment: i am worried about 'rank decreases' because of linking other sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plain link is fine:

```
<a href='http://www.facebook.com/example'>
We Are In Facebook!</a>
```

None of the testing that I've done indicates that linking to other relevant, non-spammy sites effects rankings either positively or negatively.

`rel=me` links [need to be bi-directional](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-me) to be properly implemented.  There isn't a way to get Facebook to add the `rel=me` attribute to the return link, so using it just in one direction seems pointless.   "Me" also indicates "personal."   Corporate websites would be unlikely to use it for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

For trusted sites such as Facebook, **the link structure you use will not affect the SEO of your website at all.** There is a small chance that allowing the follow will help your page on Facebook.

When you link to content, you are telling Google, "I trust this page." If you have a habit of trusting crappy pages, then Google thinks you have bad taste in friends and further assumes that your own content is sub-par, hence lowering your ranking. Therefore, if you don't want to vouch for a particular link, use nofollow.

[Google has a nice video and page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en) that explains much of its logic and provides some specific examples.